# Getting null when doing request from browser but it is not null when same is done using postman

Tags: reactjs, django, google-cloud-firestore, django-rest-framework, postman

I am using django as a backend, React as frontend and cloud firestore is my DB.
I am setting the batch id as the django session whenever any user login or create an account and the sending the request from the frontend to know which batch is currently logged in.

This is my backend code

```
class UserInHomepage(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
def list(self, request, format=None):
    print("abc",self.request.session.get('batch_code'))    
    if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
        self.request.session.create()
    data={
        'code': self.request.session.get('batch_code')
    }
    print(self.request.session.get('batch_code'))
    if data['code'] == None:
        return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And this is my frontend througn which i am requesting which user is currently logged in

```
useEffect(async ()=>{
fetch('/student/user-in-homepage/')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data.code)
})
```

},[])

But it prints **null**
And the same request on postman gives the batch id which is currently logged in.

This is the console log O/P:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/student/user-in-homepage/ 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ UserHome.js:41
invokePassiveEffectCreate @ react-dom.development.js:23487
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23574
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23447
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:23324
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:417
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:390
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:157
UserHome.js:43 Promise {<pending>}
```

Comment: Can you just log the response without the response.json() and check what is being consoled?

Comment: @CliveMachado I have added the log in the question itself now

Comment: A 400 (Bad Request) probably signifies that the server could not process an API request due to invalid syntax. Can you answer these, 

1) What PORT is your backend hosted on? 
2) What PORT is your frontend hosted on? 
3) Have you checked for A typo or mistake while building out the request manually, such as mistyping the API endpoint, a header name or value, or a query parameter?

Comment: @CliveMachado No no no as you as see in class UserInHomepage I'm sending BAD_REQUEST because data['code'] == None,                                                                         there is no syntax error as this is working perfectly on postman

Comment: If the postman call is successful try doing this, before you call the api from the frontend portal > right click to inspect element > go to network tab > now fetch the api from the frontend portal > see in the network tab which network request it is > right click on the network request > copy it as CURL > go back to postman > import as raw text > and now call again the same API > check if it throws an error.

Comment: @CliveMachado it didn't throw any error but in this code is **null** which is same state as browser